# Issues with downloading, and broken software index

Tags: update-manager, downloads

For the past couple of months now, the Update Manager has been popping up at seemingly random intervals. It has always done this, but now there's an issue. The update manager window cannot be directly interacted with, and after a minute of waiting, I get the following pop up:

[image: Popup after waiting]

When I click "close", I get the following pop up:

[image: Popup after clicking close]

At first, I thought nothing of it. But then I tried downloading Steam, and got a message saying that only one software management tool can be run at once.

I have no idea what any of this means, or how to fix it. Please note that I am not the most technologically competent person, so the simpler the wording and explanation of any solutions to this problem, the better.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

to fix it as mentioned in the 2nd dialog box.

Begin by closing the software updater windows as exclusive access is required and locks are in place if an updater is running. Continue by opening a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> and then issuing the command `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: I tried doing that, and this was the result (http://imgur.com/CFeVytV)